# How to redirect a single subdomain to a different domain?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am new to configuring Apache. I want to know how to redirect everything to another domain (`something1.original-domain.com/something2` to `http://something1.another-domain.com/something2`).

And, how to exclude a subdomain (lets say `beta`), more specifically an address like this: `something1.beta.original-domain.com/something2` from this rule and redirect it to `https://something1.some-other-domain.com/something2` with all parameters?

Thanks!

[Edit : `something?` can be blank and there may not be `.` or `/` after/before that. The protocol of original domain can be `http` or `https`.]